# What is the Big-O complexity of the following method?

Tags: algorithm, while-loop, big-o

I have a method below and I want to know the big O complexity.

```
public FinalPrepDeque<E> listUnion(FinalPrepDeque<E> lst2) {

          FinalPrepDeque<E> lst3 = new FinalPrepDeque<E>();

          Iterator<E> it1 = this.iterator();

          while (it1.hasNext()) { // O(n)
              E val = it1.next();
              if (val != null)
                  lst3.addLast(val);
          }

          Iterator<E> it2 = lst2.iterator();

          boolean found;
          while (it2.hasNext()) { // O(n)
            E val2 = it2.next();
            if (val2 != null) {

            found = false;
            it1 = this.iterator();

            while (it1.hasNext()) { // O(n)
              E val1 = it1.next();
              if (val1 != null) {
              if (val1.equals(val2)) {

                found = true;
                break;
              }
             }
            }
            if (!found)
              lst3.addLast(val2);

          }
          } // end outer-while

          return lst3;
        }
```

I know the first while loop as a complexity of `O(n)`, and the second while loop has a complexity of `O(n^2)`.  In this case, do we drop the first `O(n)` and keep the second `O(n^2)` and say this method has a complexity of `O(n^2)`?  Or do we keep it and say it has a complexity of `O(n + n^2)`?

Comment: So we just drop the lesser value of n in this case?

Comment: Downvoter, why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep the part with the largest growth rate, so O(n^2).

Comment: This answers it perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With Big-O notation, you have:

```
n1 + n2 * n3 = n + n^2 = O(n + n^2) = O(n^2)
```

The `n1` is your first `while`, the `n2` is your second `while` and `n3` is the third `while` into the second.